# jquery remove function not returning replaced html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have the following function. I am trying to remove all `<img>` tags and only the second row from table that is inside this data. The code and selectors work fine in console but I don't get the result in `data` variable after replacing all things.

```
 function fetchDetails(URLToRead, email) {
        $.get(URLToRead, function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            var imgTags = $(data).find('img');
            $.each(imgTags, function (i,v) {
                $(v).remove();
            });
            $(data).find('table tr:nth-child(2)').remove();
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
```

`URLToRead` content:

```
<TABLE>
                <TR>
                    <TD>
                        <span></span>
                    </TD>
                </TR>
                <TR>
                    <TD></TD>
                </TR>
                <TR>
                    <TD ><span ></TD>
                </TR>
                <TR>
                    <TD height="12" colSpan="4"><IMG src="../images/spacer.gif" width="20" height="7"></TD>
                </TR>
            </TABLE>
```

Comment: Are you sure that "imgTags" on line 4 is actually an array of elements that could be consumed by `$(v)`?

Comment: @jlau yes. i can debug in console and it iterates through each img tag

Comment: Add contents of `URLToRead`

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava i did

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `.remove()` works on elements that are in the `DOM`. Your `data` is never added to the `DOM`.

You can create a div with `display: none` and then perform the needed operations to it:

```js
let data = `
<TABLE>
                <TR>
                    <TD>
                        <span></span>
                    </TD>
                </TR>
                <TR>
                    <TD></TD>
                </TR>
                <TR>
                    <TD ><span ></TD>
                </TR>
                <TR>
                    <TD height="12" colSpan="4"><IMG src="../images/spacer.gif" width="20" height="7"></TD>
                </TR>
            </TABLE>
`

let tempDiv = $("<div style='display: none;'></div>")

$("body").append(tempDiv)
$(tempDiv).append(data)

$(tempDiv).find('img').remove();
$(tempDiv).find('table tr:nth-child(2)').remove();

console.log($(tempDiv).html())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks man. very nicely explained and provided the excellent solution